# Cannot resolve method getExternalFilesDir()

Tags: android-studio, directory, androidx, android-external-storage

I am migrating to android 10 and tried using `getExternalFilesDir()` instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. However, the IDE  Cannot resolve the method. Please help to fix it. Thanks in advance!

```
 public String saveImageToSD(Bitmap bmp, String filename, Bitmap.CompressFormat format) {
    File file2 = null;
    try {
        String path1 = getExternalFilesDir().toString();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(format, 100, bytes);
        File file1 = new File(path1 + "/s/Gallery/");
        if (!file1.exists()) {
            file1.mkdirs();
        }
        // Log.e("TAG", "File name : " + file1.getAbsolutePath());
        file2 = new File(file1, filename);
        try {
            file2.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fos.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
            Log.e("Success", "Final Image Saved - " + filename);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Rowan.FinalBitmap = bmp;
        FinalURI = "" + path1 + "/s/Gallery/" + filename;


        ContentValues image = new ContentValues();
        String dateStr = "04/05/2010";

        SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr);
        SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
       }
 public void mergeAndSave() {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawing_view_container.getWidth(), drawing_view_container.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    try {
        bmOverlay = MainGPUImageView.capture();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    saveImageToSD(bmOverlay, "photox_" + generateRandomName(1000000, 5000000) + ".jpg", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG);
    Log.i("TAG", "Image Created");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To interact with the external storage, you need to create a file_path.xml and also declare a FileProvider in your manifest like so:

[image: Create an XML folder in your res folder and a new file: file_paths.xml]

file_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="images"
        path="AppName" />
</paths>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.appname"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
```

After this is done, you can then call the SDK to add or remove files. If your app targets Android 6 and above, you have to request permission at runtime, and also check if the permission has been granted before attempting to access the storage.
I use Dexter to manage runtime permission. A function like so can help you achieve this.

The method that takes picture with camera, and save it to the directory:

```
private void takeCameraImage() {
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                    if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                        fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getCacheImagePath(fileName));
                        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();
}
```

The method that returns the URI of the file

```
private Uri getCacheImagePath(String fileName) {
    File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "AppName");
    if (!path.exists()) path.mkdirs();
    File image = new File(path, fileName);
    return getUriForFile(ImagePickerActivity.this, getPackageName(), image);
}
```

You can then do something with the file by overriding the onActivityResult() method.

NOTE: the `File()` object accepts two parameters: `File(File parent, @NonNull String child)` the child must match one of the paths declared in your `file_paths.xml`. In this case, I used `AppName`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling [`getExternalFilesDir(String type)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))  either within a [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context)(Example: within an Activity) or as an instance method of a Context.

`getExternalFilesDir(String type)` requires a type. You are missing one.

Choose the appropriate `type` based on what you want.
Example:`getExternalFilesDir(null)`  for the root of the files directory.

If you are looking into other `type`, from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)):

> `type` may be null for the root of the files directory or one of the following constants for a subdirectory: Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, Environment.DIRECTORY_PODCASTS, Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES, Environment.DIRECTORY_ALARMS, Environment.DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, or Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES.

> If you supply a non-null type to this function, the returned file will be a path to a sub-directory of the given type.